# class, interface, or enum expected in runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a simple program for implementing runnable. i'm getting an

```
import java.util.*;


class NewThread implements Runnable{
    Thread t;

    NewThread(){
        t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread "+t);
        t.start();
    }
}

public void run(){
    try{
        for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
            System.out.println("Child Thread:"+i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("Child Interrupted");
    }

    System.out.println("Child Thread Exiting\n");
}


public class ThreadDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thread curr = thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("Current Thread"+curr);  
        new NewThread();

        try{
            for(int i=0;i>5;i--){
                System.out.println("Parent Thread"+i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Main Thread Exiting");      
    }
}
```

i get these errors while compiling

> ThreadDemo.java:14: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
>   public void run(){
>    ^
> ```
>
> ThreadDemo.java:16: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
>   for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
>               ^
> ```
>
> ThreadDemo.java:16: class, interface, or enum expected      for(int
>   i=5;i>0;i--){
>                         ^
>
> ThreadDemo.java:18: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
>       Thread.sleep(1000);             ^
> ```
>
> ThreadDemo.java:19: class, interface, or enum expected      }       ^
>
> ThreadDemo.java:22: class, interface, or enum expected   }   ^
>
> ThreadDemo.java:25: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> }

Comment: The `run()` method should go _inside_ of the `NewThread` class.   You are closing the class with an extra `}` after the constructor.

Comment: Another fine example why you should use a fully featured IDE for developing Java...

Answer (score 1):

You have closed the definition of your class before including the `run` method. Check here:

```
class NewThread implements Runnable{
    Thread t;

    NewThread(){
        t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread "+t);
        t.start();
    }
} // <-- remove this
public void run() {
    //implementation...
}
//<-- add the } here
//rest of your code...
```

---

Apart from the notorious error other people points, your design is pretty odd. A `Runnable` should not contain a single `Thread` to execute its job since the `Runnable` will be executed by another `Thread`. This is an overview of your threads current design (or how it should behave):

```
Main thread
    |
    | ---->   new NewThread(pass the Runnable)
    |              |
    |              |
    |              |
    |              |  ----------------------->  new Thread().start()
    |              |                                     |
    |              |                                     |
    .              .                                     .
    .              .                                     .
    .              .                                     .
```

This is how your code should look like:

```
import java.util.*;

class NewThread implements Runnable{
    //a Runnable shouldn't have another thread
    NewThread() {
    }
}

public void run(){
    for (int i=5;i>0;i--) {
        System.out.println("Child Thread:"+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            //interrupted exception will somewhat wake the thread up
            //so it must handle the Thread#sleep method only.
            System.out.println("Child Interrupted");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Child Thread Exiting");
}

public class ThreadDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thread curr = thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("Current Thread"+curr);
        //pass the runnable to a thread and start the thread
        new Thread(new NewThread()).start();
        for (int i=0;i>5;i--) {
            System.out.println("Parent Thread"+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Main thread interrupted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Main Thread Exiting");      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `run()` method inside your `NewThread` class

Comment: @rajsherror make it work doesn't mean you're learning. Note the update on my answer to see how you should work with `Thread` and `Runnable`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I would add a link to the Oracle tutorial on concurency. Nice edit, but you don't explain **why** it should be like that, or what your edit changes to the OP code.

Comment: It is explained in the *graphic* I made.

Comment: By the way, since my answer is CW anybody can freely edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `run` method is outside the class

Answer (score 0):

Methods should be enclosed in the class. You have put the end brace '}' before the run method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewThread implements Runnable{
    Thread t;

    NewThread(){
        t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread "+t);
        t.start();
    }
// modify remove this }     
//}

    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
                System.out.println("Child Thread:"+i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Child Interrupted");
        }

        System.out.println("Child Thread Exiting\n");
    }
// modify add this }    
}

public class ThreadDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //modify thread curr = thread.currentThread();
        Thread curr = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("Current Thread"+curr);  
        new NewThread();

        try{
            for(int i=0;i>5;i--){
                System.out.println("Parent Thread"+i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Main Thread Exiting");      
    }
}
```